# Laravel 5.2 Sessions not persisting

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, routes

I've searched a lot before posting and every 'solution' that I've found did not work.

I can't get a session value from a different route than the current one.

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'blog', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Blog\Http\Controllers'], function()
{

Route::get('/','PostController@index');

Route::get('/home',['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PostController@index']);

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');

Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');


 Route::group(['middleware' => 'blog.auth'], function(){
  Route::get('/admin',['as'=>'dashboard','uses'=>'AdminController@index']);
  });
 });
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \ommitedbutcorrect\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
    ],

    'admin' => [
        \Modules\Admin\Http\Middleware\ControllerResolver::class,
    ],
    'admin.auth' => [
        \Modules\Admin\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
    ],
    'blog.auth' => [
        \Modules\Blog\Http\Middleware\BlogAuthenticate::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;


protected $redirectTo = '/blog/admin/';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

public function login()
{
    dd(\Session::get('foo'));
    $userdata = array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password')
    );

    if (\Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
        \Session::save();
        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        }
        else{
            return 'f*ck';
    }
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    \Session::put('foo', 'bar');
    return view('blog::Admin.login');
}
```

Chmod 777 on Storage and Bootstrap folders, session driver database.

It seems that the session is creating itself every time with the request that would explain why I can't get the the value with Session:get('foo') which now returns null.

I wasted 3 days on this already :/.

Would appreciate the help, if you guys need more details / code just say the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by clearing the cache with php artisan cache:clear

I got my project from another person so no matter what changes I did, it used the cached settings(in this case it was using DB sessions and I wanted to use file-based sessions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Laravel ships with session middleware in the wrong array, but move the StartSession middleware into the protected middleware group

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

Comment: Just did, still printing Null.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was because you use modules instead of the default structure laravel provided.

all routes bind with the web middleware by default in laravel 5.2, however, you use modules and each module has a separated routes.php file. You have to manually bind the routes with the web middleware again otherwise, your session will lost.

That was what I did when I met a similar problem. Please let me know my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Laravel >= v5.2.27, you need to remove the `web` middleware from your `app/Http/routes.php` file. As of v5.2.27, all routes inside the `app/Http/routes.php` file are already included in the `web` middleware group, so adding the middleware again inside the file messes with the sessions.

Comment: Mine is version 5.2.39, If I remove web middleware from the routes file it doesn't work either (even the laravel_session does not get created)

Answer (score 0):

What new Service Provider signed up?

Comment: Errrm, come again?

Comment: show me the array 'providers' => [...] of config/app.php file